# Identity based encryption

Tags: finite-groups, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, hash-function

I am implementing ID based encryption  in c# right now i am having problem at the following mathematics

$$H_1: \{0,1 \}^n \times \{0,1 \}^n \to \mathbb{Z}^*_p, \text{ what does this expression mean?}$$
P is prime number.
G's are groups of finite orders.
H's are hash functions

What is the difference among the following expressions?

$$
\begin{align}    
H_2: & \{0,1\}^n \to G \\
H_3: & \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n \\
H_4: & G_1 \to \{0,1\}^n .
\end{align}
$$

I am pretty new user dont even know how to format equation here?

Comment: Thanks.Please tell me how you input formatted text.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! No problem. You can see the code by clicking to edit the post to see what I changed. We use LaTeX here. I don't remember if there's a thread teaching LaTeX, but there's a [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) to help you with the commands.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you get your answer! :)